# SqlContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

this is my build.sbt file:

```
name := "words"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.3.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"  % "1.3.0"
)
```

sbt.version=0.13.8-RC1

When I compile the program, I have the following error:

```
    [error] D:\projects\bd\words\src\main\scala\test.scala:8: 
            type SqlContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
    [error]     val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SqlContext(sc)
    [error]                                               ^
    [error] one error found
    [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `SQLContext` not `SqlContext`.